# Android: Retrieving User profile picture from User class in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to get the current user followers in a list-view inducing their names and profile pictures, I have two classes in parse :
User class: includes ( username and pic columns )
and following class: includes ( username and follower_name columns )

now here my query :

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
// Create the array
users = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
try {
      ParseUser currentuser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
      ParseQuery<ParseObject> innerQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("following");
      innerQuery.whereEqualTo("username", currentuser);
      ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
      query.whereMatchesQuery("username", innerQuery);
      // by ascending
      query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
      ob = query.find();
      for (ParseObject user : ob) {
      // Locate images in pic column
      ParseFile image = (ParseFile) user.get("pic");

      UserInfo map = new UserInfo();
      map.setUserName((String) user.get("follower_name"));
      map.setPic(image.getUrl());
      users.add(map);

    }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
 }
```

I'm a new parser and trying to learn their queries

Update :

I change the query to be like this:

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        users = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
        //ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();


        try {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("following");
            query.whereEqualTo("username", "suma");
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> a = ParseUser.getQuery();
            a.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("username", "follower_username", query);
            a.orderByAscending("createdAt");
            ob = a.find();
            for (ParseObject user : ob) {
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) user.get("pic");
                UserInfo map = new UserInfo();
                map.setUserName((String) user.get("username"));
                map.setPic(image.getUrl());
                users.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Only if the user have one follower, it work fine otherwise (many followers) the app crashes

Please Help ?

Comment: just throw your complete code ..also post the log messages

Comment: Your comment says Locate images in flag column, but your code gets the file in "pic" column. Which is correct? Put a log statement after that and see if you actually get a file

Comment: sorry guys I hope that it's much clearer now :")

Comment: I can easily write my query in SQL but how to convert it into Parse queries that's the issue, Any good links I can learn from ? especially User class queries.

Comment: If you designed this with a SQL database in mind (and it seems you did), you will probably experience scaling problems. You should read the tutorial on Parse.com for the app Anypic. Although it is for iOS, it should give you a good primer on how to design for NoSQL (like Parse). There are also a couple of attempts at Android Anypic ports, like https://github.com/bhaskarmurthy/anypic-android     I would also recommend reading about the Twissandra project (a Java/Cassandra clone of Twitter).

Comment: Don't create a new ParseUser currentUser. You should just use ParseUser.getCurrentUser() where-ever you need it. Also, you can't compare "username" to ParseUser (currentUser). You would need to get the "username" property from the ParseUser (like you do with "follower_name").

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
// Create the array
users = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
try {
      ParseQuery<ParseObject> innerQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("following");
      innerQuery.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("username"));
      ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
      query.whereMatchesQuery("username", innerQuery);
      // by ascending
      query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
      ob = query.find();
      for (ParseObject user : ob) {
      // Locate images in pic column
      ParseFile image = (ParseFile) user.get("pic");

      UserInfo map = new UserInfo();
      map.setUserName((String) user.get("follower_name"));
      map.setPic(image.getUrl());
      users.add(map);

    }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
 }
```

This should be more in tune with what you need, but I don't think this will work (although I can't say for sure not knowing your data model). In your current model, you would probably have a pointer to the user column in the following class. You then need to compare the object itself; not username.

Comment: sorry that's didn't work, Please help me in retreaving more than one record in my updated query